# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

Here is my Angular code

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.message ='this is  message';
});
```

And my template code is

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">  
  <div>{{ ctrl.message }}</div>
  <img src="img.gif">
</div>
```

Issue is Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…t%20d%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2FD%3A%2Fangular%2520js%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

What could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: please try and google this . If you then have any doubts please ask here.

Comment: Try using the un-minified version of angular.js whilst developing; the error messages are more verbose. Also, try and paste the actual link it gives you in the console error message

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you set a scope variable `$scope.message` but in the expression a variable which is defined as controllers instance variable is expected.

A valid expression for a scope variable is `{{message}}`.

A valid expression for a variable which is defined as controllers instance variable:

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  this.message = 'this is  message';
});
```

is `{{ctrl.message}}`

See this code example for a better illustration: http://plnkr.co/edit/HunVdGVYaC0HLjDPmWKl?p=preview

Comment: Whilst this is correct, I don't think it would cause the error OP's getting

Comment: @Phil you are totally right, sorry!!! I fixed what was obviously wrong in the provided code (and didn't checked the error case). If `message` is not defined, angular will simply not render it.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without the entire error message but it appears to be an `$injector` issue which usually points to missing dependencies. Will just have to wait an see